# Python basic function program

Tags: python

i am new to python and i have been asked to make a program with a function in it.

```
##Write a program that converts between centimetres, and inches and vice versa, by:
##asking the user to input a number
##asking the user to choose between converting from centimetres to inches or from inches to centimetres
##calculating and outputting the result using functions

number = int(input("Please enter a number"))
print ("Please write 'one' if you would like to convert from inches to centimeters"/n "please write 'two' if you would like to convert from centimeters to inches.")

def one():
             print("Your number is", number*2.54, "in centimetres")

def two():
             print ("Your number is", number/2.54, "in inches")

             return
```

When my program is running, it just says "syntax error" and does not run.

Any help would be appreciated - thank you.

Comment: You are missing a `)` after `number = int(input("Please enter a number")`

Comment: thank you for the help, but unfortunately the program is still not working.

Comment: Update your code, explain what is failing. Clearly show the error message that is coming up. A copy paste of the stack trace would be best.

Comment: It just says invalid syntax as soon as i run it. @idjaw

Comment: Update your original post with your latest code and provide the full error message as shown.

Comment: You will still have to write code to call yout function `one` or `two`.

Answer (score 5):

**First Problem**

You are missing a closing bracket on this line:

`number = int(input("Please enter a number")`

You should have this:

`number = int(input("Please enter a number"))`

**Second Problem**

You are trying to convert "one" to an int. You can't do that. You need to re-think your approach on how you want to take user input to determine which method you want to execute. You can stick to using "one" and "two". But try doing this instead:

`number = input("Please enter a number")`

From there you should use a simple conditional statement to call whichever method you want to call. I will leave that up to you to figure out.

**Third Problem**

You are not using the newline character properly. You can't set a newline the way you were doing it. Firstly, the proper usage of newline character is `\n` and must be inside your quotes. So your line should look like this:

```
print ("Please write 'one' if you would like to convert from inches to centimeters\nplease write 'two' if you would like to convert from centimeters to inches.")
```

Comment: thank you for the help, but unfortunately the program is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be working with these changes.

```
number = int(input("Please enter a number")) 
print ("Please write 'one' if you would like to convert from inches to centimeters \n please write 'two' if you would like to convert from centimeters to inches.") 

def one(): 
    print("Your number is", number*2.54, "in centimetres") 

def two(): 
    print ("Your number is", number/2.54, "in inch")
```

Comment: Just corrected the syntax error of the original code to get it running as requested.

This issue is a logic error of the program not validating input.